# The great Deception

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew, eschatology

I would like to know what different denominations teach about what the great deception is exactly. One so great that even the very elect, if possible, would be deceived.

> For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect.
>
> Matthew 24:24 KJV

Comment: I have added the text to which I think you are referring, for the sake of clarity. Please free to edit or remove. Requesting the interpretation of all denominations on this most various of subjects (prophecy and the last times) makes it a very broad question indeed.

Comment: Thank You Nigel! I don't specify the denominations to gather contrast between them. I would love for different representatives from each to answer to gain clarity.

Comment: If there are different answers for different denominations, how is someone supposed to decide which is best? Since there is one objective answer ("This is what denomination group A says, this is what B says,..."), we need each answer in a survey question like this to at least try to explain every denomination's viewpoint (or at least the major ones). I don't know how many major views there are on this, but potentially it could get quite difficult to account for all of them in one answer.

Comment: Even within some denominations, there are several different interpretations!